# Calling one php page in html page from one website to another

Tags: php, html

I have one index page with footer-new.php as include. I also have one page called offers.php on some other site. I just need that offers.php file to be called in footer-new.php. Offers.php file contain one .gif banner and nothing else. I wanted that banner to be placed in my footer.php.

Please help me with the code. I tried, `fopen()`, `header(Location:)`, and i also tried `include""` and `require""`.

I could not load offers.php file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack OverFlow! Please include some code for diagnosis.

Comment: why do you have to use php for this? go to your other site right click on the banner, copy the "image location" and put it in an `<img>` tag

Comment: the fact that i even have to ask that means you didn't include enough info. please be specific.

Comment: i don use , because i will be uploading dat banner on all the site.. That banner contain one click here link that might change in future. that is why i created php file so dat once i do changes it will be automatically updated on all the sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply do

```
echo file_get_contents("offers.php");
```

in your footer-new.php

This will display the complete page in footer-new.php